# How to get size of a file using C#?

Tags: c#, file

I am retrieving a file from a specified path and storing it in a temp folder. But the size of a file differs between 1KB to 2 KB.

I am using,

```
File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\temp\" + newFile + "__" + fileName, versionNumber);
```

The lines are copied to the new file and stored in a temp folder. But the size is not accurate.

I would like to know how to get size of a file using C#.

Can anyone help me with any suggestions would be a great helpful. Thank you.

Comment: How are you getting the size? Are you getting the actual size, or the size on disk (which may include padding)?

Comment: It sounds like you are *copying* a file, so why not `File.Copy`?

Comment: Since I am retrieving file using List<string> newFile = new List<string>(); by using File.Copy throwing me an error couldn't find the specified file.

Comment: @Sunny you comment does not make much sense... your `newFile` is an empty list. Where does the content come from? If you *read* it from a file, then `File.Copy` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(@"c:\temp\" + newFile + "__" + fileName);
long fileSizeInBytes = fi.Length; //size in Bytes
```

Comment: I used the below code and its work for me, thanks for the suggestions.                                                                                          System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(newFile);
long fileSizeInBytes = fi.Length;

Answer (score 0):

Use a `File.Copy`  method, like this:

```
File.Copy(path, path2);
```

You can get more info from MSDN:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a(v=vs.110).aspx